# i am getting this error stating that I cannot find modules

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

I am getting a problem where it says that i cant find the module . The errors that I go is posted below : I am currently using Ionic 4. I am not sure but does ionic 4 support the angular functionality ?

```
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts(1,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts(2,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/database.d.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/list/audit-trail.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/list/changes.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/list/snapshot-changes.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/list/state-changes.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/observable/fromRef.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(1,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../../../node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,79): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase'.
```

This is my app.module.ts file. Do i need to update my rxjs and update my angular ? i am not sure about what to do .

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],


  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],


  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,



    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and this is my package.jason

```
  "name": "event-manager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "1.0.0-beta.19",
    "@capacitor/core": "1.0.0-beta.19",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.9.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/node": "~10.14.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I was messing around with

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Quiz } from '../services/event/quiz.interface'; 
import { EventCreatePage } from '../pages/event-create/event-create.page';
import {AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  quiz = {} as Quiz; 
  eventcreatePage = EventCreatePage; 


  quiz$ : AngularFireList<Quiz>;



  constructor (private database: AngularFireDatabase,private router: Router) { 
    this.quiz$ = this.database.list('quiz');

  }

  onclick (quiz : Quiz){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('EventCreatePage, quiz');
  }
}
```

Comment: did you install your `node_modules`

Comment: Yes. I tried installing it again .  it has the same error .

Comment: You don't have any `@angular/fire` in your dependencies.

Comment: `@angular/fire` is not in your dependency or you can do a `npm i --save @angular/fire`

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/fire` is not in your dependency or you can do a `npm i --save @angular/fire`

Comment: I just did a npm i-- save @angular/fire but it didn't work .

Comment: same error you are getting? try clearing npm cache, delete node_modules folder  and reinstall it again

Comment: I cleared and did everything . It still doent work .

Comment: I put a .ts file in my question. I was messing around with this when that happened